# Is there an alternative to Google Maps to find GPS coordinates of a place in Germany?

Tags: geospatial, api, location

For probably any place on Earth, you can search it in Google Maps, make right-click, pick the option "What's here" and you get GPS coordinates.

[image: english-school]

If I don't want to use Google Maps API, is there an alternative open API to get GPS coordinates by address? To be less broad, say in Germany?

Comment: Hi @J. Doe, try searching this site for questions related to "geocoding".  You will see answers to posts like [this one](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/543/7031) (i.e. try OpenStreetMap as an alternative to Google Maps).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Nominatim which is a geocoding search engine built on Open Street Map (OSM) data.

https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search.php?q=Zentralbibliothek+Z%C3%BCrich

[image]

Click "details" --> https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?place_id=84442764
and you'll see latitude/longitude and metadata of the entry

---

You can either use an API, or run your own Nominatim server (which can be done for individual countries).

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

https://nominatim.org/release-docs/develop/api/Overview/